# How to draw on tk.Text widget?

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need to draw rounded rectangles around some words in a tk.Text widget. How to do this? Is there some kind of Text's internal "canvas"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want; there is no internal canvas on which to draw.

You can highlight regions of text, and place a border around regions of text, but you can't draw on it.